# How can I ask an executive for an old position back?

Tags: professionalism, communication

I work at a rather large company. In April, a C-level executive announced he was looking for someone. He's very notorious for giving everyone his private email but seldom responding to any non-important messages, but I decided to take a chance and email him. Surprisingly, he granted me a position just under him. I could do the work, but it was my first time in such a high-level position. I went on a power trip and ended up doing practically nothing for the company. Graciously, instead of being fired, I was demoted back to my original position. I quit anyway out of frustration, believing my demotion unreasonable.

It was only recently I realized what a fool I was. I was handed the golden ticket and threw it away. A few weeks ago, I rejoined the company. I promptly emailed the executive an apology. The issue is, in that apology, I explicitly stated I didn't want a second chance. I only wanted to apologize. He did not respond to my apology.

I would now like my position back. The executive is still actively looking for someone, and I'm confident I can do the work while not going on a power trip. How can I ask that executive for that job without reneging on my apology?

Comment: "I explicitly stated I didn't want a second chance" - sounds like you're still on a power trip. Who are you to give an executive such an unprompted directive?

Answer (score 11):

You can simply ask directly.

Don't get your hopes up though: You have made a bunch of serious mistakes and you have established a track record of "not knowing what you want" and "changing your mind on a dime".

This has probably done significant damage to your reputation and the only way to fix this is to STOP doing that. Sending the exec a message "Hey, I just told you that I don't want the job, but I have changed my mind again" is not going to help.

Comment: It should be noted that badgering executives even more could get OP fired :) As I understand, he is rehired but lower then his old position.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately this is probably not a situation that will be fixed by "I'm sorry, please give me another chance".

Here's what you did (if I am reading this correctly):

- You asked a C-level executive for a significant position
- You were given that position and it's responsibilities
- You had a "power trip" and did essentially nothing
- You were offered your old position back, which you took
- You felt wronged, so you quit
- Somehow they accepted you back (not sure if this is in your original position or not)
- Now you realize you were wrong and want the position the C-level had given you

Now, whether you *could* do the work or not, you didn't. The best way to remedy this situation is to put your head down and work hard, producing results for the company. When this comes up in time, after rebuilding your reputation, you may be able to re-apply. I wouldn't push this any further than the apology. Let your results talk for you, begging for your old position under the exec is likely to get you on a list you don't want to be on (if you aren't already). Being given your job back was as much second-chance as you'd probably get.

My advice would be to offer a 1-on-1 to apologize (and that's it). Tell the exec that in time you hope that your work speaks for itself and you are interested in advancing for the company, but don't beg for your old job.